# Erro em document.getElementById() no Brackets

Tags: javascript

Está dando este erro na imagem quando uso "document". Alguém sabe como resolver isso? Já pesquisei aqui mesmo no stack e não achei nada que me ajude. Detalhe, que estou usando o Brackets.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Henrique, será que você poderia postar o código? Com uma imagem e apenas um pedaço do código fica um pouco difícil te ajudar. Quando mais informações você fornecer, mais chances você tem de ter uma boa resposta.

Comment: Verifica se o brackets está com a verificação de sintaxe para HTML ou JavaScript no canto direito inferior, se não estiver mude.

Comment: Quais as extensões que tem instaladas no Brackets?

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda galera, era o que o Sergio falou abaixo! Obrigado a todos!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esse aviso é do programa que verifica a sintaxe do código, um dos mais populares (e talvez o que tenhas) é o ESLint.

Esse erro deve ser ignorado se esse código é para correr no browser, pois `document` é uma global no browser.

Para corrigir isso vai ao ficheiro de configuração do ESLint e junta

```
env: {
    browser: true,
```

para dizer ao linter que esse código corre no browser

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu!!!